# Python save cookies from first get, use in other requests

Tags: python, cookies

I like to pass cookies between my requests since they all depend on that. 
I do a GET request to a url. I like to save the cookies form response and use those cookies in the following next posts.

I have done the following:

```
import requests, http.cookiejar

s = requests.Session()
g1 = s.get('testURL')
jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

p1 = s.post('another URL', headers=headers, data=data, , cookies=jar)
```

When I print the "jar" it is empty and the process is not working.  How can I save cookies from the first request and pass it on to other requests?

how do I save the cookies after g1 request? so I cna pass it to p1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Session` object does the cookie handling for you automatically. So if you don't specify different cookies in your post request, the cookies that you got in the original GET will be sent back to the server. The [docs for the request library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#advanced) have some good basic examples of this.

Comment: I learned this the hard way, you are correct, python is great it keeps all cookies throughout the session

Comment: once I create a session, do I need to close that session? I am worried of keeping dangling sessions if I run my tests over and over

Comment: If I use--> with requests.Session() as s:  then maybe it is safer since I wont have so many dangling sessions

Comment: It's a great idea to use `with requests.Session() as s:`! It's exactly what it's there for. (P.S. if you're happy with the answer, you can accept it so that others see that you got a good answer.)

Comment: Thank you Win, I did accept it (I thought) I usually use "with requests.Session() as pS:" However there is this one scenario where I need the same exact session for multiple test cases where each test case sends "pass" or fail so I will need the "pS"  in other test cases , so thats why I cant use "with"  so how can I close or terminate the session at the end of my tests?

Comment: After more reading I saw the following not sure which works:  pS = requests.session(config={'keep_alive': False})  or pS = requests.Session()
then at end 

requests.session().close()

Comment: You want to call the .close() method on your session when you're done with it. The "keep_alive" part is for passing a configuration option to the library to reuse the same HTTP connection where possible, which it does automatically now, and you don't need to worry about it with Requests.